# Binary Search - Find Index of Target in a Given Array

Tags: python, c++, binary-search

This is the first problem on binary search at leetcode. We're asked to return the index of a target at a given array. My first attempt at a solution was the following:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int result = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            if (nums[i] == target)
                result = i;
          
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

If I don't place return result twice I get a message of time exceeded for some reason. Anyhow, for the array and target below this piece of code returns the nonsensical value of 16 when it should return 4:

```
[-1,0,3,5,9,12]
9
```

I discussed with a friend and he came up with a solution in Python in the same spirit:

```
class Solution(object):
    def search(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        l = -1
        for i in nums:
            l += 1
            if i == target:
                print(l)
                return l
```

This one worked perfectly. I don't see how it differs much from the one in C++ though. Is this somehow related to how Python and C treat indices? Why does the C++ solution doesn't work? Sorry if these are all very silly questions, I'm rather new to programming in general. Any help is welcomed.

Edit: I fixed the loop condition to `i < nums.size()` which I hadn't noticed before. That fixes the time exceeded problem I was getting and allows me to place the return outside of the for loop, however now I'm getting the value of 6 for some reason.

Edit 2: Fixed the `if` statement to `result = i`, that solved everything. Kudos to Mark for noticing this very silly mistake. All is good now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Here in for(int i = 0; nums.size(); i++)   condition part "nums.size()" will always be true. You should write like "i<nums.size()" checking if i is less everytime

Comment: This is not a binary search. Binary search is a certain, specific algorithm. Unfortunately, all these useless online quiz sites are just a collection of puzzles, without giving any necessary background in computer science which are needed to implement them. Here, for example, you don't get an explanation of what a binary search is all about, and its algorithm. You will only find it in a good computer science, and/or C++ textbook, and not on some useless online quiz site that nobody cares about. If your goal is to learn C++, you will find a good textbook to be more useful than leetcode.

Comment: As @SamVarshavchik states this is not a Binary Search it's just linear Search.

Comment: If you really want to do a binary search, 1. The sequence must already be sorted, and 2. You can just use `std::lower_bound`, which does 95% of the work for you. If you don't care about where the item is (i.e. you're only looking for true/false on whether it is in the sequence) you could just use `std::binary_search` and throw this entire thing out.

Comment: Something about code returning `16`. You didn't initialize `result`, so it can have any value, for example, `16`. You always return in the first iteration of the `for`, and if the first element is not what you're searching, then `result` won't change

Comment: What do you expect `i = result` to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Eduardo, I believe this was the critical mistake here. I thought placing it outside the loop would solve this issue but now It's returning a value of 6.

Comment: I see your point Mark, I changed it to result = i and that fixed the problem. Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Explains it on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
- Here is a Binary Search in C++:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;

static const struct Solution {
    static const int search(
        const std::vector<int>& nums,
        const int target
    ) {
        ValueType lo = 0;
        ValueType hi = std::size(nums) - 1;

        while (lo < hi) {
            ValueType mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

            if ((nums[0] > target) ^ (nums[0] > nums[mid]) ^ (target > nums[mid])) {
                lo = mid + 1;

            } else {
                hi = mid;
            }
        }

        return lo == hi && nums[lo] == target ? lo : -1;
    }
};
```

- In Python:

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums, target):
        if not nums:
            return -1
        lo, hi = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while lo <= hi:
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            if nums[mid] == target:
                return mid
            if nums[mid] >= nums[lo]:
                if nums[lo] <= target <= nums[mid]:
                    hi = mid - 1
                else:
                    lo = mid + 1
            else:
                if nums[mid] <= target <= nums[hi]:
                    lo = mid + 1
                else:
                    hi = mid - 1
        return -1
```

- Here is one of LeetCode's official Solution, commented as well:

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        def find_rotate_index(left, right):
            if nums[left] < nums[right]:
                return 0
            
            while left <= right:
                pivot = (left + right) // 2
                if nums[pivot] > nums[pivot + 1]:
                    return pivot + 1
                else:
                    if nums[pivot] < nums[left]:
                        right = pivot - 1
                    else:
                        left = pivot + 1
                
        def search(left, right):
            """
            Binary search
            """
            while left <= right:
                pivot = (left + right) // 2
                if nums[pivot] == target:
                    return pivot
                else:
                    if target < nums[pivot]:
                        right = pivot - 1
                    else:
                        left = pivot + 1
            return -1
        
        n = len(nums)
        
        if n == 0:
            return -1
        if n == 1:
            return 0 if nums[0] == target else -1 
        
        rotate_index = find_rotate_index(0, n - 1)
        
        # if target is the smallest element
        if nums[rotate_index] == target:
            return rotate_index
        # if array is not rotated, search in the entire array
        if rotate_index == 0:
            return search(0, n - 1)
        if target < nums[0]:
            # search on the right side
            return search(rotate_index, n - 1)
        # search on the left side
        return search(0, rotate_index)
```

- Python does not have `int` overflow (`mid = start + (end - start) // 2`). Here is another official Solution of LeetCode for this problem:

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        start, end = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while start <= end:
            mid = start + (end - start) // 2
            if nums[mid] == target:
                return mid
            elif nums[mid] >= nums[start]:
                if target >= nums[start] and target < nums[mid]:
                    end = mid - 1
                else:
                    start = mid + 1
            else:
                if target <= nums[end] and target > nums[mid]: 
                    start = mid + 1
                else:
                    end = mid - 1
        return -1
```

Comment: The last code snippet is for a different problem (find rotate index).